# How To Join Relative URLs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, relative-path

I want to join two strings each representing a relative URL in Javascript.

I want to join the base URL `http://www.adress.com/more/evenmore` with the following examples:

1. `../../adress` (with the expected output: `http://www.adress.com/adress`)
2. `../adress`  (with the expected output `http://www.adress.com/more/adress`)

What would be the best way? I was thinking of using regexp and checking
how many `../` preceed the relative URL, then subtracting that amount from the baseurl and adding them to what is left.

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following function decomposes the URL then resolves it.

```
function concatAndResolveUrl(url, concat) {
  var url1 = url.split('/');
  var url2 = concat.split('/');
  var url3 = [ ];
  for (var i = 0, l = url1.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (url1[i] == '..') {
      url3.pop();
    } else if (url1[i] == '.') {
      continue;
    } else {
      url3.push(url1[i]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0, l = url2.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (url2[i] == '..') {
      url3.pop();
    } else if (url2[i] == '.') {
      continue;
    } else {
      url3.push(url2[i]);
    }
  }
  return url3.join('/');
}
```

Comment: I modified this where your testing for '.' to also test for empty string `url1[i] == '.' || url1[i] == ''` so if the passed in URLs have slashes it still composes a valid URL. +1

Comment: this doesn't seem to work as expected. /a + ./b = /a/b and it should be /b

Comment: @GordonTruslove: Maybe this solves your issue, it gets rid of the **a**.  `url1[ url1.length-1 ] = ''`

Answer (score 88):

8 years later, many browsers (except for Internet Explorer) support the [URL constructor (`URL(url [, base])`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL).

```js
> new URL('../address', 'http://www.adress.com/more/evenmore/').href
"http://www.adress.com/more/address"
> new URL('../../address', 'http://www.adress.com/more/evenmore/').href
"http://www.adress.com/address"
```

Comment: Here's a [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams) for IE.

Comment: It should be noted that relative does not mean relative to the full path but relative to the last directory path. `new URL('bar', 'http://example.com/foo)` will result in `http://example.com/bar` not `http://example.com/foo/bar`

Answer (score 8):

Using URI.js ([urijs - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs)): [`absoluteTo()`](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#absoluteto):

```
function joinUrl(baseUrl, url) {
    var theUrl = new URI(url);
    if (theUrl.is("relative")) {
        theUrl = theUrl.absoluteTo(baseUrl);
    }
    return theUrl.toString();
}
```

Comment: These days there's no real need to use a library.

Comment: This library option works if you have to relative URLs to combine. Because ECMAScript's URL throws an error:

  new URL("../the_relative_url", "rel/path/")
  TypeError: URL constructor: rel/path/ is not a valid URL.

Comment: I'd almost want to add that to your answer. That's a great justification for avoiding URL, especially on the front end where access to Node.js native modules isn't supported.

Answer (score 7):

The ECMAScript `URL` Web API mentioned by @ning is a good place to start: especially as it is available in vanilla JS implementations (Node, etc.) *and* doesn't require you to use a library that does something the implementation nowq already accomplishes. Consulting the MDN documentation, more [specifically the examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Examples), is a great place to start.

Borrowing (somewhat) directly from their documentation:

```js
let m = 'https://developer.mozilla.org';

// ... omitted 

let d = new URL('/en-US/docs', m);
```

If you were to do the above, then `console.log` the [.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/toString) of the constructed `URL` object, your output would be: `'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs'`.

Importantly, if you consult the Syntax section of the documentation, you will note that the **second** argument is optional and the **second** argument (as seen in the above example) represents the *base* URL (though only in the case of two arguments being supplied).

If both argument values are absolute URLs, Web API honors the first and discards the second.

If you are working with Node.js, I would encourage you to look at the native [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module for doing work on relative paths, again over using a library. The main motivation here is that spinning up your own algorithm (probably just a call to `path` here and there) is potentially better than introducing a library that will pull in several other dependencies that may introduce vulnerabilities and unnecessary bloat to your application (or just be too heavy weight for what you need).

However, if you are working on the front end, you won't have `path` available to you and - as mentioned in [@cburgmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057171/3469725) comments - Web API's `URL` doesn't support the relative path case mentioned. In this case, you may need to look for a library to accomplish this for you; however, again, given the other answers, I'd consider trying out a home-spun approach.

To their credit, `URI.js` currently only integrates [one non-dev. dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uri-js) and doesn't have a huge footprint.